# Defining a measure on a topological space turns it into a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces

If I have a topological space $(E,t)$ and define a measure on $E$ will that imply that I have a metric space?

By that I mean defining a sigma-algebra $S$ in $E$ and then a measure function $m:S \to \overline{\Bbb R}$, then will there be an metric function $n$ such that $(E,n)$ is a metric space?

How can I properly verify this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you intend to do with $t$?

Comment: a topology in $E$

Comment: Of course. I'm asking what you plan to do with it in your construction.  Do you ignore it?

Comment: yes. what do you mean by "my construction"? my attempts?

Comment: I mean the definition of the $\sigma$-algebra and the measure function.  If you ignore $t$, you are essentially starting from a set.

Comment: @Crostul. Is the wikipedia definition wrong then?

Comment: A metric space is not a measure space. They are two different things. Why should you have a metric when you have a measure?

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi. Oh, sorry, I misread your first comment with "what is $t$?". Actually, while reading the second comment of Crostul I recognized that maybe I'm not healthy enough to think at this right now. Thanks. But please (moderator) don't exclude the topic because I'll be back later.

Comment: [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402847/whats-the-relationship-between-a-measure-space-and-a-metric-space) seems relevant

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, it was VERY relevant and informative. I don't need this question anymore. Thank you very much and to anyone in this thread.

Comment: You can turn the measurable $\sigma$-algebra module the null sets into a metric space (if the measure is finite), using $d(A,B) = \mu(A \Delta B)$, using the symmetric difference operator. There is no clear way to make the space itself a metric space that I heard of.

Answer (score 0):

you won't have a metric space because in a metric space you can calculate DISTANCES between points and eventualy sets ( you can define that as the inf of the distances of points x in   X and y in Y) . On the other hand , defining a measure allows you to calculate the SIZE of the sets which are in your sigma algebra.

Comment: But what do I have in a metric space that makes me be able to calculate distances?

Comment: @Alnitak A metric.

Comment: For a finite measure $\mu$, convergence in measure is pseudo-metrizable.

Comment: Theoretical Economist, by calculating you meant then the possibility of assuming a value in a field for two points, but not a method on how to do it? I guess I don't know what calculate means. I can see why I can't take the infimum mentioned in the answer. Is that what calculate means?

Comment: Calculate can mean different things depending on the context you are working with ! That is , depending on the metric defined on your metric space . A metric can be any function satisfying : d(x,y)=0 if and only if x=y , d(x,y)=d(y,x) , d(x,z)<=d(x,y)+d(y,z), d(x,y)>=0.. sorry if the notation was a bit confusing , but d is a function defined on the space you are turning into a metric one and x,y and z are points in that space